# calling onCreate method from inside another method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, oncreate, sqliteopenhelper

I have never seen anyone explicitly call one of the system callback methods like onCreate() or onDestroy() from inside another method.  It just looks wrong. I thought I saw this in some example and I can not believe it. Is it my imagination or was it real?

in the code below for the onUpgrade() method of an SQLiteOpenHelper class, I am calling the onCreate() method explicitly from another function.  Is it possible to call onCreate() from inside this method?  and is there a better way to do this without calling onCreate()?

```
 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     DatabaseHelper(Context context){
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + LentItems.NOTE_ID + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
             LentItems.TITLE + " TEXT, " + LentItems.TEXT + " TEXT);");

     }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int previousVersion, int newVersion) {
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
     onCreate(db); // <-- EXPLICIT CALL TO ONCREATE
     }

 } // end DatabaseHelper inner class
```

Comment: Why are you even doing this and not using `startActivity()`?

Comment: i saw the call to onCreate() used on some example, however if a call to startActivity() is a better way I will try that instead

Comment: Am I in living in another universe? why are all the comments and answers suggesting you to use startActivity? I thought this thing you're showing us is about SQLiteOpenHelper? So it should be calling `new DatabaseHelper(context)` instead? And NO, onUpgrade will be called after onCreate, there is no need to explicitly call onCreate in onUpgrade, that is one of the very bad example.

Comment: @Kevik sorry, I saw `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` and jumped the gun thinking you were talking about starting a separate `Activity` from there

Comment: @Chor WaiChun where is the document that say that onUpgrade is called after onCreate?

Comment: i found some more examples where explicit call to onCreate() is used inside of the onUpgrade() method.  http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html   http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/

Comment: @Kevik onCreate would not be called, so when you add new tables you can either create it in onUpgrade or change the onCreate method to create new table there and call onCreate in on upGrade.

Comment: I admit it is my mistake on the sequence of onUpgrade and onCreate, only one of them will be called. But, first, referring to your first example, the call of onCreate is done on a class which does NOT extends any related classes, it is a plain function which just simply named as onCreate. As for second example and Hoan's answer, do an alter table statement in onUpgrade, not DROP. Does dropping all data in a table sounds good to you? just because you want to change the table's structure? Imagine dropping all user's setting detail and reassign all default value for him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call there is correct, onCreate() is only called once when the database is first created. onUpgrade is called when the database version is changed. Thus when you drop the table in onUpgrade you have to call onCreate there to create new table with the onCreate changed to reflect the new table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, onUpgrade() is an abstract method in SQLiteHelper, so does not automatically call onCreate().

Yes, it's weird to see a lifecycle method called externally, but it is correct in this case. This particular (naive) implementation of onUpgrade() blindly drops the table and re-creates it in the same manner as the first database creation. For an app where you don't need to save user data on a database upgrade, this is a shortcut that works just fine.

It would probably make a little more sense to have a private createTableName() method for each table and then call those methods in *both* onCreate() and onUpgrade(). After all, it's not a good general practice to simply "forget" all user data every time you push an app update with a change in database structure. It would make more sense to *only* drop and re-create the tables that have changed. Even then you'd want to temporarily "save" the user's data and dump it into the newly created table, accounting for new/deleted columns. Alternatively, if your app saves user data to a server, you can drop and recreate all the tables, then trigger a sync immediately afterward.